# Gogs installation Error

Tags: git, nginx, centos7, failed-installation, gogs

Environment
OS : **Centos7**

Panel : **VestaCP (Nginx)**.

Domain : **my.exgitrepo.com(locally)**

IP : **192.168.1.13(locally)**
User: **admin**

In my /home/admin/my.exgitrepo.com/public_html/ i downloaded gogs binary, unzip it and run `./gogs web`

Filled up forms on **my.exgitrepo.com:3000** with application url `http://my.exgitrepo.com:3000/` and domain `my.exgitrepo.com`

When press install browser says `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

And console

```
[admin@271-appdevelopment-box public_html]$ ./gogs web
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ WARN] Custom config '/home/admin/web/my.exgitrepo.com/public_html/custom/conf/app.ini' not found, ignore this if you're running first time
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [TRACE] Custom path: /home/admin/web/271.git.com/public_html/custom
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [TRACE] Log path: /home/admin/web/271.git.com/public_html/log
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [TRACE] Log Mode: Console (Trace)
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ INFO] Gogs 0.11.29.0727
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ INFO] Cache Service Enabled
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ INFO] Session Service Enabled
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ INFO] SQLite3 Supported
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ INFO] Run Mode: Development
2017/10/07 17:33:01 [ INFO] Listen: http://0.0.0.0:3000
[Macaron] 2017-10-07 17:33:19: Started GET / for 192.168.1.131
[Macaron] 2017-10-07 17:33:19: Completed GET / 302 Found in 288.498µs
2017/10/07 17:33:19 [TRACE] Session ID: e39a6882496f8db1
2017/10/07 17:33:19 [TRACE] CSRF Token: GbC454VgjEUCw1Ry_do3P2GkXcU6MTUwNzM3Nzc5OTA1MzYxOTgxMQ==
[Macaron] 2017-10-07 17:33:19: Started GET /install for 192.168.1.131
2017/10/07 17:33:19 [TRACE] Session ID: e39a6882496f8db1
2017/10/07 17:33:19 [TRACE] CSRF Token: GbC454VgjEUCw1Ry_do3P2GkXcU6MTUwNzM3Nzc5OTA1MzYxOTgxMQ==
2017/10/07 17:33:19 [TRACE] Template: install
[Macaron] 2017-10-07 17:33:19: Completed GET /install 200 OK in 35.710305ms
```

Below response when clicked on install

```
[Macaron] 2017-10-07 17:38:21: Started POST /install for 192.168.1.131
2017/10/07 17:38:21 [TRACE] Session ID: e39a6882496f8db1
2017/10/07 17:38:21 [TRACE] CSRF Token: GbC454VgjEUCw1Ry_do3P2GkXcU6MTUwNzM3Nzc5OTA1MzYxOTgxMQ==
2017/10/07 17:38:23 [TRACE] Custom path: /home/admin/web/my.exgitrepo.com/public_html/custom
2017/10/07 17:38:23 [TRACE] Log path: /home/admin/web/my.exgitrepo.com/logs
2017/10/07 17:38:23 [TRACE] Log Mode: File (Trace)
2017/10/07 17:38:23 [ INFO] Gogs 0.11.29.0727
```

I can see database created with tables and logs files are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging couple of hours, I came to know this is Issue with permission of public folder.

```
chown admin:admin -R /home/admin/web/my.exgitrepo.com/public_html/public/
```

**gogs**, Console output hangs because of permissions and show no output regarding permissions issue.